# Iterate over buttons in ButtonGroup QML

Tags: qt, button, qml

I have a bunch on `Button` in my `QML` application.
Since there are many buttons on the same page it might be difficult for the user to see which button was pressed last!
So I would like to change the last Button font to indicate it was pressed, but later when another button gets pressed I would like to restore its font again.

I can not find a good way to do this.
I tried connecting all buttons to a `ButtonGroup`, but I need to iterate through all the buttons in order to `set underline to false` but however I try to do this I get different type of error.

Please see the example below:

```
Button {
    text: qsTr("Open")
    ButtonGroup.group: buttonGroup
    font.pointSize: 20; font.family: "Courier"
    onPressed:  { /* some action here*/ }
    onReleased: { /* some action here*/ }
}

Button {
    text: qsTr("Close")
    ButtonGroup.group: buttonGroup
    font.pointSize: 20; font.family: "Courier"
    onPressed:  { /* some action here*/ }
    onReleased: { /* some action here*/ }
}


ButtonGroup {
    id: buttonGroup

    function underlineButtons(underlined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
            children[i].font.underline = underlined;
        }
    }

    onClicked: {
        console.log(" -------------- buttonGroup Clicked: ", button.text)
        underlineButtons(false)         // restore old buttons
        button.font.underline = true    // mark the last button clicked
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error what ever I do to try to access the children element.

```
qrc:/main.qml:65 ((null)): qrc:/main.qml:65: ReferenceError: children is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

You can either

- iterate on the `children` of the parent of your buttons
- or iterate on the `buttons` of your `ButtonGroup`.

**Long answer**

Every QML Item has a children property, containing all Item-inherited children.
It means that you can iterate over the children of an item, like any other list of elements.

```
Item {
    id: container

    function setUnderlineOnChildren() {
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
            children[i].font.underline = true; 
        }
    }

    Button {}
    Button {}
    Button {
        onClicked: {
            container.setUnderlineOnChildren();
        }
    }
}
```

`ButtonGroup` is used to create mutually exclusive checkable buttons (like radio buttons) as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-buttongroup.html). But contrary to most QML elements, because it does not represent a graphical element, it inherits QtObject instead of Item. So it won't have the `children` property of Items. But you should be able to do the same, relying on the `buttons` property by adding to the above

```
ButtonGroup {
    id: myGroup
    buttons: container.children

    function underlineButtons(underlined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
            buttons[i].font.underline = underlined; 
        }
    }
}
```

And then calling `myGroup.underlineButtons(true)`.

Comment: Could you please update the ButtonGroup with your suggestion. I can not find children in buttonGroup!

Comment: ButtonGroup is a bit different as it inherits QObject (or QtObject in QML), and not the standard Item. I'll elaborate above.

Comment: I tested this solution but I am getting type error. please see above

Comment: This did the trick, buttons[i].font.underline = underlined; I am accepting your answer as it pointed to the right direction

Comment: Was it a typo on my side? I cannot find the difference with my answer. I can update it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the activeFocus property and then in the font you can query whether or not the button is in active focus.

```
Button {
    text: qsTr("Open")
    font.pointSize: activeFocus ? 30 : 20
    font.family: "Courier"
    onPressed: {
        activeFocus = true
        /* some action here*/ }
    onReleased: {/* some action here*/ }
}

Button {
    text: qsTr("Close")
    font.pointSize: activeFocus ? 30 : 20
    font.family: "Courier"
    onPressed: {
        activeFocus = true
        /* some action here*/ }
    onReleased: {/* some action here*/ }
}
```